# Why do strtotime(' ') and strtotime('.') return a timestamp?

Tags: php, strtotime

After some messing around with strtotime() in PHP I noticed that it gives a valid timestamp back when you pass in spaces and or dots.

```
var_dump(strtotime(" "));
var_dump(strtotime("."));
var_dump(strtotime(". .. .. .. .... .. . .. ."));
```

produces:

```
int 1443009652
int 1443009652
int 1443009652
```

Why does PHP see this as valid?

Comment: You're passing in strings....what would you expect it to return?

Comment: Probably because it tries to parse so many potential strings like "next Thursday", "+3 days", "now", "first Tuesday of last month", "23 September 2015", etc that it simply defaults to current date/time if it can't make sense of the string, rather writing an error to output

Comment: Hey, it works with commas too!

Comment: Interesting question: _Why are you doing that_?

Comment: It should return 'false' on something it can't parse it as a date/time according to the documentation.

Comment: Then [raise a bug](https://bugs.php.net/) if you think that this is incorrect behaviour

Comment: it takes default date and time and return a timestamp

Comment: Seriously, what the hell is this: ',. ., ,. .,1 week ,. ., 2 week,. .,3 week'

Comment: Yes, but why?
`strotime("bogus");` returns FALSE as expected. I would expect that `". .  . ... ..  "` would return FALSE too as there is no way I can see that it is parsable as something close to a date/time

Comment: Perhaps because dots, commas, spaces, slashes, dashes, etc ae all typically found as separators in date formats that can be passed to strtotime() whereas `strtotime("bogus")` is all purely letters.... but without wading through the PHP source cde, you're not going to get an answer to why, only speculation

Comment: Thanks. I'll file a bug and see what they have to say about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is some of them are `false`y

```
var_dump(DateTime(false)); // date shown is current time
```

My bet is that the parser (which is trying to clean up a wide variety of acceptable inputs) strips the periods out (that are not being used as a delimiter), leaving only an empty string. It's the only explanation that makes sense.

```
echo strtotime('1.1.2000'); // outputs 946681200
```

Comment: This is probably the case. I would expect that `strtotime(' ')` and `strtotime('')` would give the same output though, but they don't.
I'll file a bug and see if they can clarify this behaviour.

Comment: In which version `echo strtotime(false);` return the timestamp? i test here and got  false. php5.6.8

Comment: i have no willingness to go through this function http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_2/ext/date/php_date.c#1125  and php 5.1.0 http://pastebin.com/LYE0n7g3 may be you have

Comment: Ill mark tour answer as correct for now. I filed a bug report but no reaction as of yet.